# text render issue ( overwriting )in cinnamon debian

Tags: linux, debian, fonts, cinnamon, debian-stretch

After I installed DEbian 9 with cinnamon , I came across this childish issue. it's kind of a problem I will not expect in a professional OS.

[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tua5r.png)

The problem has been solved by changing Gedit's theme for gedit , but this is still happening on the package installer and etc  screens.

Why is this problem being raised?  And how do I solve this problem?

[Gedit with in a state of ruin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WswIz.jpg)

[Package İnstaller with in a state of ruin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKyVc.png)

I using intel i5 with hd 3000.  But ı dont think it is a driver issue. I used many debian variations and they all worked fine for years.

Comment: Display driver issue?

Comment: I used a lot of debian variations on this computer and never encountered that kind problem.  And using same gpu years. Because that my first thought was not driver issue. Other things like video players works flawless.